# FeathersJs: Cannot set headers

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

I am trying to set the content-type header on a route in a [feathersjs](https://feathersjs.com/) app.

I keep running into this error - `error:  Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

This is how I am trying to set the headers --

```
const myService = {
  create(data, params) {   // create == POST request
    console.log(data);
    return Promise.resolve(); 
  }
};

function setContent(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
  res.end();
  next();
}

app.use('/incoming', myService, setContent);
```

I am guessing `return Promise.resolve();` also sets the header. How do i go about overriding that?

Comment: try `app.use('/incoming', setContent, myService);`

Comment: Tried. Generates the same error.

Comment: try to remove `res.end()` from `setContent`

Comment: App starts returning a 404 on the route

Comment: maybe b/c of empty Promise.resolve(), try Promise.resolve({})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not coming from your middleware but the Feathers one registered *after* because you are ending the response with `res.end()` and then *still* calling `next()` which is probably not what you want. It should be either

```
function setContent(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
  res.end();
}
```

Or

```
function setContent(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
  next();
}
```

Also, service methods always have to return an object, so it should be at least `return Promise.resolve(data);` or `return Promise.resolve({});`

Comment: I am trying this exact code, but I either have it that I get the right content-type and no data or I get the data and the wrong content type: 
My service line looks as follows: 
````app.use('/users', createService(options), setContent);```` 
createService comes from here: 
````const createService = require('feathers-sequelize');````

Comment: Solved it by doing:
`const setContentType = (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(res.data)); // data is JSON object
  res.end();
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call middleware before calling the service,
try this

```
const myService = {
  create(data, params) {   // create == POST request
    console.log(data);
    return Promise.resolve(); 
  }
};

function setContent(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
  next();
}

app.use('/incoming', setContent, myService);
```

Comment: Doesn't build. `Unexpected token {` error at second line.